# Tkinter showing strange artifact on Mac

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I have built some GUI's using tkinter in python (3.7) and I am noticing that when some of the widgets are selected when run on mac (ventura 13.3.1 m2 mac mini) they show a strange spike in the highlight on the left side.

[image: Submit button with artifact]
[image: Dropdown Menu with artifact]

My code is simple, but here's an example for the button just to let you know I'm not doing anything crazy:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import platform
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

def run_program():
    print("Run command ran")

def main():
    # This initializes the GUI
    root = Tk()
    root.title('COD_FISH Input')

    # create a notebook (the pages)
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    notebook.pack(pady=10, padx=10, expand=True, fill='both')

    main_frame = ttk.Frame(root)

    button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Submit', command=run_program)
    button.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky='se', padx=5, pady=5)
    # makes it so that hitting 'Enter' triggers the submit button.
    button.bind('<Return>', run_program)

    # This tries to see if the program is being run on windows and
    # if so changes a setting which improves the resolution of the GUI
    if os.name == 'nt':
        from ctypes import windll
        windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

    # This is what constantly updates the window.
    root.mainloop()

# This protects the script from running many times! Not sure why it would do that though
# since it isn't called anywhere else...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # And this prevents the pyinstaller .exe file from opening the window many times
    # due to incompatibility with multiprocessing
    mp.freeze_support()
    # Specific multithreading fix for Macs
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    main()
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is there something that I can add to remove this strange artifact?

I ran this on python 3.7. I tried with 3.11, and it was still present (as well as there being problems with the dark mode, with white text of a white background showing up)

Comment: `from tkmacosx import Button`  Remove `ttk.Button` to `Button`

Comment: Provide detailed debugging information including Python distribution, Python version, etc. Did you try [the recent official distribution](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3113/)?

Comment: I am developing this code to work with mac and windows so I'd prefer to not have to edit each widget for each OS, or to make messy `if import` statements. I ran this on python 3.7. I just tried with 3.11, and it was actually worse due to my mac being in dark mode, and the text being white on a white background for some of the widget. Also the artifact was still present in 3.11.

Comment: tkmacosx does fix the button issues, even in dark mode, but there aren't entries in this package. I was hoping this would be addressable in the tkinter code, or some modification I could make.

Comment: What distribution are you using? I tried [the official one](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.3/python-3.11.3-macos11.pkg) and it works fine on my Ventura 13.2.1. I guess you are using a wrong Tcl/Tk library.

Comment: Using the distribution fixed it, although it was very challenging to do since I'm used to using conda environments. I had to open up the python executable manually and install required packages using python-3.11 -m pip install, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking through different python versions, the most recent python version worked well in mac. So just note that for current macs, to get tkinter to work well, you'll need the most current python and Tk.